# Postgresql- providing password in the command prompt window pg_dump

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am using Postgresql EDB 9.3 in linux server . Since i need to automate the database dump process. I am facing problem to provide the password in the command prompt while executing the script .

My solution can be provided in either way :-
1. Through the command prompt script execution 
2. By framing  a shell script that can take the dump

Pgdump command used by me -

/chroot/iqmsdb/PostgresPlus/9.2AS/bin/pg_dump -F t -E utf-8 -U iqmsuser -p 5444 -f iqmswiki_27aug2015.backup -i -h 172.17.161.176 iqmswiki

Currently i am providing password when the command prompts to enter the password. but that does not solves my purpose . Please help me

Comment: you can save assword for this user to .pgpass or make `trust` for `local` connection for that user

Comment: Totally unsecure but simple: `PGPASSWORD=*** pg_dump ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot Abelisto ... it worked,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a .pgpass file to store the password. For details see the manual:

> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: For me on windows machine, setting the password like  this without quotes worked: SET PGPASSWORD=1234